# A nested Angular submenu doesn't hide properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have menu with a submenu made with Angular 2 that will collapse and expand whenever the person clicks on it:

### This is how it SHOULD look like:

[image] *Clicked on Admin ->*[image]

---

### This is how it looks like now:

[image: This is how it looks like] *Clicked on Admin - >*
[image: This is how it looks when you expand it]

In order to make it look like the first I have to add a next `<a>`
element after the nested menu in order to make it work. If I delete the last 'child' it will look like the second image.

The code for this looks like this

file names in order of appearance:

- Sidebar.ts
- Some relevant CSS (.nestedmenu)
- Sidebar.html

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'sidebar-cmp',
    templateUrl: 'sidebar.html'
})

export class SidebarComponent {
    showMenu: string = '';
    isActive = false;
    addExpandClass(element: any) {
        if (element === this.showMenu) {
            this.showMenu = '0';
        } else {
            this.showMenu = element;
        }
    }
    eventCalled() {
        this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    }
}
```

```css
.nested-menu {
    .list-group-item {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nested {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    ul.submenu {
        height: 0;
    }
    & .expand {
        ul.submenu {
            list-style-type: none;
            height: auto;
            li {
                a {
                    color: #FFF;
                    padding: 10px;
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="toggle-sidebar" type="button" (click)="eventCalled()">
        &#9776;
        </button>
<nav class="sidebar" [ngClass]="{sidebarPushRight: isActive}">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <a routerLink="/dashboard/home" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item">
            <span class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>
            </span> Dashboard
        </a>
        <div class="nested-menu">
            <a class="list-group-item" (click)="addExpandClass('pages')">
                <span><i class="fa fa-users"></i> &nbsp; Admin</span>
            </a>
            <li class="nested" [ngClass]="{'expand' : showMenu === 'pages' }">
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>
                        <a routerLink="/dashboard/admin/device" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']"> Device </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a routerLink="/dashboard/admin/device" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']"> Sensor </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <!-- If this part is commented out it'll break the submenu above-->
        <a class="list-group-item">
            <span class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>
            </span> Test
        </a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

What should I do to make it also work without adding something after the submenu? If I have to provide more code I'll do so.

Comment: Could you show the problem in plunker?

Comment: I don't know how to properly do this so instead I'll add a preview to the SB Admin http://rawgit.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-2/master/dist/prod/dashboard/chart. If you can then remove the elements after "menu" in the sidebar you'll notice that the same behavior happens. For the code here: http://startangular.com/product/sb-admin-bootstrap-4-angular-2/

Comment: http://rawgit.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-2/master/dist/prod/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-2/issues/48

Answer here:

> .I had the same problem. Just edit your _app-base.scss located in the
>   assets/sass/ folder as I show you:
>
> `.nested-menu {
>       .list-group-item {
>           cursor: pointer;
>       }
>       .nested {
>           list-style-type: none;
>       }
>       ul.submenu {
>           height: 0;
>       }
>       & .expand {
>           ul.submenu {
>               list-style-type: none;
>               height: auto;
>               li {
>                   a {
>                       color: #FFFFFF;
>                       padding: 10px;
>                       display: block;
>                   }
>               }
>           }
>       }   & .hidden {
>       visibility: hidden;   } }`
>
> then you must edit each div menu in the typescript file sidebar.ts in the  following way:
>
> `<div class="nested-menu">
>               <a class="list-group-item" (click)="addExpandClass('pages')">
>                   <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Menu</span>
>               </a>
>               <li class="nested" [ngClass]="{'expand' : showMenu === 'pages',  hidden: showMenu !== 'pages' }">
>                   <ul class="submenu">
>                       <li>
>                           <a href><span>Submenu</span></a>
>                       </li>
>                       <li>
>                           <a href><span>Submenu</span></a>
>                       </li>
>                   </ul>
>               </li>
>           </div>`
>
> And that's all! :)